# How can I launch a PDF file in Java?

Tags: java, file, javafx

I created a Java application on Netbeans and I want to launch a PDF file when clicking a button.

What I did first was placing the file "manual.pdf" in the directory where I have my classes and I tried this code:

```
if(Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
     try {
          File file= new File("manual.pdf");
          Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
     } catch(IOException ex) {...}
```

but when I ran it, it said that the file didn't exist, so I put

```
System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

in order to see the path of the file it was trying to open and it was

```
C:\Users\adrian\Documents\Mis Programas\Convertron\manual.pdf
```

but the file was in

```
C:\Users\adrian\Documents\Mis Programas\Convertron\src\org\sicadcam\convertron\manual.pdf
```

It was looking for the file in the root directory of the project.

When I placed the file `manual.pdf` in the root directory it worked, but, when I ran the executable jar in the dist directory, it didn't.

Then I tried with

```
File file = new File(ConvertronController.class.getResource("manual.pdf").toExternalForm());
```

just to see what happens, but it didn't work.

How can I make so that it looks for the file in the same directory where the class is?

Or where should I place the file so that when I build the application it keeps working?

Answer (score 6):

You can put the PDF document in a Java package, e.g. `resources`, like the next project structure:

```
TestProject
|
\---src
    |   
    +---org
    |   \---paulvargas
    |       \---test
    |               OpenTest.java
    |               
    \---resources
            manual.pdf
```

For open the file:

```
package org.paulvargas.test;

import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class OpenTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
            // File in user working directory, System.getProperty("user.dir");
            File file = new File("manual.pdf");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                // In JAR
                InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()
                                    .getResourceAsStream("resources/manual.pdf");
                // Copy file
                OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            }
            // Open file
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thakns for answering. I Tried it and when I printed the path of the file I think it was correct, it says it is `C:\Users\adrian\Documents\Mis%20Programas\Convertron\dist\run1978651465\Convertron.jar!\recursos\manual.pdf`, but it doesn't open the file. I opened the jar file in order to make sure the file `manual.pdf` is in the correct directory and it is. I don't get any error message, it just doesn't open it.

Comment: That's correct. In that case, you need copy the file in JAR to some directory. I update my answer for that. Good luck!

Comment: Since this question is tagged with JavaFX I think this might be of interest: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36339

Answer (score 0):

I've used this is the past:

`getClass().getResource("a_file.txt");`

In this case, the class from which this is called is in the same directory as `a_file.txt`.